# Probe data collection in python by RS 485

Tags: python, putty, rs485, probe

Hello I'm stuck with problem. I have probe (Vaisala DMT 152) with RS 485 communication line. The manufacturer make some commands in PuTTY. What I need is connect with probe in python and start read data. Any help is welcome.

Thanks for your suggestion links and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The manufacturer make some commands in PuTTY.

`PuTTY` is SSH and Telnet client. First step is to find if communication with device is through SSH or Telnet. If first you would need find python module which does offer SSH client functionality ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/) is first place to look for external python modules), if second take look at [`telnetlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) which is part of standard library. Then look into manual of device, which should have descripition how to ask it and implement it using appropiate client.